# Using Jacobi Elliptic Functions to solve Euler's Equations of Motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

Recently, I have been trying to use Jacobian Elliptic Functions to solve for angular velocities in the Euler's Equations of Motion, which look like this:
$$
I_1\dot\omega_1-\omega_2\omega_3(I_2-I_3)=0\\
I_2\dot\omega_2-\omega_3\omega_1(I_3-I_1)=0\\
I_3\dot\omega_3-\omega_1\omega_2(I_1-I_2)=0
$$
Where $I_n$'s are constants. According to [this paper](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/bg268/EulerTop.pdf), if we assume that $I_1<I_2<I_3$, we can express the angular velocities $\omega_n$ as:
$$
\omega_1=\sqrt{
\frac{L^2 − 2T I_1}{
I_1(I_3−I_1)}}
sn(\tau, k)\\
\omega_2=\sqrt{
\frac{L^2 − 2T I_1}{
I_2(I_3−I_2)}}
sn(\tau, k)\\
\omega_3=\sqrt{
\frac{L^2 − 2T I_1}{
I_3(I_3−I_1)}}
dn(\tau, k)
$$
Where $L$ and $T$ are expressed by:
$$
L^2=I_1^2\omega_1^2+I_2^2\omega_2^2+I_3^2\omega_3^2\\
2T=I_1\omega_1^2+I_2\omega_2^2+I_3\omega_3^2
$$
However both are constants, so the only thing needed to express them are the three $\omega_n$'s at some point in time.
$\tau$ and $k$ are the following:
$$
\tau=\sqrt{\dfrac{(L^2−2TI_1)(I_3−I_2)}{\sqrt{I_1I_2I_3}}}
dt \\
k=\sqrt{\dfrac{(I_2−I_1)(2TI_3−L^2)}{(I_3−I_2)(L^2−2TI_1)}}
$$
My question is the following: If I want to use the Jacobian functions to find $\omega_n$, assuming that I know all the $I_n$'s and the initial $\omega_n$'s, do I just input all the values into the function, substituting RHS of the ninth equation for $\tau$ and treating $dt$ as $t$? I have tried that, but the results were different from when I used Mathematica to numerically integrate the first three equations. Also, sometimes a hole in the graph appeared when using the Jacobian function - the graph wasn't continuous. What am I doing wrong?

Also, one of the assumptions stated in the article was that $t=0$ when $\omega_2=0$. Obviously, I followed this assumption, but what should I do if I want to integrate for a case when $\omega_2$ does never equal? Or if it does at some point in time, but that point is unknown and only some other non-zero initial conditions are given?

Comment: In the paper, the $d$ in equation(16) is a typo. The expression for equation(22) also have typos, the one appear in the formula of $\omega_1$  should be $cn(\tau,k)$. I'm not sure about the correctness of that scaling constant, you should check it again. Another thing you should know is Mathematica uses a different convention for the arguments in Jacobic elliptic function. For example, the $m$ in `JacobiSN[z, m]` is equal to $k^2$ in the paper.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. If you also know the answer to the last question "What if I want to choose a different starting point that $\omega_2=0$", than you should post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Since the derivatives of the three basic Jacobi elliptic functions are, (Hille,Zwillinger)

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\, \mathrm{sn}\,(z) = \mathrm{cn}\,(z)\, \mathrm{dn}\,(z),$$

$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\, \mathrm{cn}\,(z) = -\mathrm{sn}\,(z)\, \mathrm{dn}\,(z),$$

$$   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\, \mathrm{dn}\,(z) = - k^2 \mathrm{sn}\,(z)\, \mathrm{cn}\,(z). $$

with some re-arrangements they could be be directly expressed as required.