# Jacobi Elliptic Functions as solution to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

Let $S$ satisfy $S^i_{jk} = S^{i}_{kj}$. What is the general solution of the differential equation

$$ \dot{w_i} = S^{i}_{jk} w_jw_k \quad  (i= 1,2,3)? $$

(Summation notation is used.)

I'm fairly sure the general solution consists of sums of Jacobi elliptic functions, but I end up with too few degrees of freedom when I try a solution of the form $w_i(t) = a_i \text{ sn }v t + b_i \text{ cn } vt + c_i \text{ dn } vt$.

Comment: Did you try for the equation in $w_1,w_2$ solutions of the form $w_i(t)=\sum_r \frac{c_{i,r}}{t-b_{i,r}}$

Comment: I should mention each $S^i$ has zero diagonal. I'm not sure the above ansatz works with this assumption.

Comment: Are matrices $S^{i}$ with constant or time dependent entries ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The matrices are constant.

Comment: Why do you think that the solution should be in terms of elliptic functions? Is your S special?

Comment: I see no reason for functions (sn,cn,dn) to be have such a "general fame" to be solutions to so general equations. To get more or less convinced of that, **interpret** your system (with one differentiation degree more on both sides) as a system of geodesic differential equations : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solving_the_geodesic_equations whose solutions are - in general - not connected to Jacobi elliptical functions.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1483615

Comment: @user8268 As Jean Marie linked, at least one choice of $S$ results in elliptic functions. In my case, each $S^i$ is the commutator of a diagonal matrix and and an antisymmetric matrix (and hence a symmetric zero diagonal matrix).